# Apply formula to column

Tags: google-sheets

I need help to make a formula to apply to the entire column (column D) so that if I add/remove a row everything stays with the formula

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14LFutwrMf7gtffL6aTm4PhRNBMlgHIdvGzP90Efzt28/edit?usp=sharing

I have tried adding an array, but I must be doing something wrong, I can't make it work. I have shared an example sheet. Can someone please give me a help.

Answer (score 1):

It should just be

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A:A="","",hyperlink(A:A&B:B,"SMS")))
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, just had to replace the , with a ;